# Firestore security rules allow update if array does not contain uid

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Regarding Firebase Firestore security rules, I need something like

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.map
```

But allow update if map does NOT contain auth.uid.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: u want both if present or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
  allow update: if !resource.data.map.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
```

Corresponding doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List

PS: Note that the name of the Array field which contains the uids is `map` (you get its value through `resource.data.map`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data). It may be less error-prone to rename to this field to e.g. `uidsArray` and do `resource.data.uidsArray.hasAny(...)`